# Shimano Alivio M4000 vs Altus M370 shifters

Tags: shimano, shifter

I'm planning to upgrade my shifters to Alivio M4000. My old shifters are Altus M370. My question is will this make a significant differrence on my shifting? I'm running Altus M310 FD with Alivio M4000 shadow RD

Answer (score 2):

When you upgrade shifters (provided you have the right compatibility), you're paying for (or trading off between):

- Lower weight
- More strength/durability
- Reliability

In the sense that Alivio > Altus, you should be getting some of these.

However, if your shifters and what not are in good condition (i.e. good cable runs, shifters in good condition, derailleur in good condition), I don't think you'll notice (much).

Comment: Thanks mate what a quick reply. Even though I can get Alivio shifters for $25 ('bout 275.000 IDR in Indonesia), my Shimano Altus shifters are still really good and never disappoint me so far. My mechanic also said the same thing the other day, that Alivio and Altus won't make a really significant difference. Weight won't be a problem for me.